# Customer viewer count doubles once I refresh my Django webpage

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I tried implementing a viewer count functionality on a website i'm working on. It seemed to be working well at first but I realised that when I refreshed a page the count added twice as opposed to once. What might be the problem?

I am using class based views.

```
class IdeaDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Ideas
    template_name = 'strathideasapp/ideas_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        object = super(IdeaDetailView, self).get_object()
        object.view_count += 1
        object.save()
        return object
```

Comment: or add many to many field to user and add user to Idea on authenticated  view bases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to count in **init** method as it is called only when object is created

```
def __init__(self):
    object = super(IdeaDetailView, self).get_object()
    object.view_count += 1
    object.save()
    return object
```